# How to use GROUP BY in SQL

Tags: sql, group-by

I have 2 tables (roads + loads), and I want to make this action:

```
sprintf(my_cmd, 
"SELECT road.id 
FROM road,load "
"WHERE road.id=load.id ORDER BY road.id "
"GROUP BY road.id");
```

but I get an error:

> Error executing query: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "GROUP" LINE 1:
>   ... road,load WHERE road.id=load.id ORDER BY road.id GROUP BY r...

Why is that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`ORDER BY` comes after `GROUP BY`:

```
sprintf(my_cmd, 
"SELECT road.id 
FROM road,load "
"WHERE road.id=load.id GROUP BY road.id "
"ORDER BY road.id");
```